# I can't make my Polymer project load in phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, polymer

I just started playing with the Polymer Gmail App,

https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-gmail

I tried to archive the folder, and upload it to phonegap build, and than check it on android, and nothing happenes after loading the application.

Is there anything that has to be added to any of the steps so polymer will work well in phonegap?

Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What Android version are you trying to run it on? Polymer won't work in the older Android stock web views (i.e. default in Android 4.3 & lower). You can however use CrossWalk to package an app with a Chromium based web view - https://crosswalk-project.org/ - in Android 4.0+.  Or if you run on Android 4.4+ you'll get a Chromium based web view by default.

A CrossWalk option is coming to PhoneGap Build supposedly in the near future.

Comment: Make that 4.4.3+.   On 4.4.3 it is supported with polyfills, and on earlier versions it is not supported.